# WCF Load tests does not run as concurrent as possible

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

I'm trying to do some load testing on my WCF Service But my Client Seems to only Be sending 10 requests at a time.  I have a dummy service set up just to sleep for the number of seconds passed in and then return the managed thread Id.

I've added configuration to up my max connections and set the max MaxDegreeOfParallelism to Int.MaxValue

My test runs parallel with the Max DegreeOfParalleism set to max int.

```
var warmupService = GlobalFactory<ICountryService>.Instance;
warmupService.Dummy(0);

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = int.MaxValue };

var results = new ConcurrentBag<FullTimeInfo>();
Parallel.ForEach(range, parallelOptions, i =>
{
    var fullTimingInfo = new FullTimeInfo();
    var timingInfo = new TimingInfo();
    fullTimingInfo.Timinginfo = timingInfo;

    var seconds = timesVaraiance[i % timesVaraiance.Count];
    fullTimingInfo.ExpectedSleepTimeSeconds = seconds;

    var isw = new Stopwatch();
    timingInfo.StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    isw.Start();
    timingInfo.ThreadId = warmupService.Dummy(seconds);
    isw.Stop();

    timingInfo.WCFExecutionTime = isw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    timingInfo.EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    results.Add(fullTimingInfo);                
});
```

I'm running 100 requests that will sleep for 3 seconds. Here is a portion of the results:

> "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:37 AM","ThreadId":17,"WCFExecutionTime":3004}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:40 AM","ThreadId":16,"WCFExecutionTime":6027}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:43 AM","ThreadId":17,"WCFExecutionTime":9029}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:46 AM","ThreadId":9,"WCFExecutionTime":12030}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:49 AM","ThreadId":17,"WCFExecutionTime":15030}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:52 AM","ThreadId":9,"WCFExecutionTime":18033}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:55 AM","ThreadId":17,"WCFExecutionTime":21034}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:38:58 AM","ThreadId":9,"WCFExecutionTime":24037}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:34 AM","EndTime":"11:39:01 AM","ThreadId":9,"WCFExecutionTime":27039}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:35 AM","EndTime":"11:39:04 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":29050}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:36 AM","EndTime":"11:39:07 AM","ThreadId":9,"WCFExecutionTime":31054}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:37 AM","EndTime":"11:39:13 AM","ThreadId":8,"WCFExecutionTime":36052}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:37 AM","EndTime":"11:39:10 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":33061}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:38 AM","EndTime":"11:39:16 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":38066}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:39 AM","EndTime":"11:39:19 AM","ThreadId":8,"WCFExecutionTime":40069}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:40 AM","EndTime":"11:39:25 AM","ThreadId":8,"WCFExecutionTime":45041}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:40 AM","EndTime":"11:39:22 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":42072}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:41 AM","EndTime":"11:39:28 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":47081}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:42 AM","EndTime":"11:39:31 AM","ThreadId":8,"WCFExecutionTime":49083}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:43 AM","EndTime":"11:39:37 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":54058}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:43 AM","EndTime":"11:39:34 AM","ThreadId":6,"WCFExecutionTime":51087}}
>   "StartTime":"11:38:44 AM","EndTime":"11:39:40 AM","ThreadId":15,"WCFExecutionTime":56097}}

As you can see after the first 9 requests it seems like it waits for a bit before sending the next request.  What else can I do to optomize the preformance to send more requests?

Comment: Have you tweaked our wcf service with concurrency modes and Throttling  behavior?

Comment: Turns out it was the thread pool I upped the minimum number of threads

Comment: So now your requests are fine?

Comment: Yeah now everything ms working thanks

Comment: It would be more helpful if you answer your own question in step by step how you resolved and what parameters you considered as load balancer is a big issue in real time.